# Saving attempted inputs to replace front-end validation (PHP)

Tags: php, validation, user-input, client-side-validation

While looking for a way to speed up form validation on a large number of fields I build my own library of php validation functions to be re-used across multiple websites. I am now trying to avoid duplicating these rules in javascript without sacrificing user-friendliness.

I am thinking of storing attempted inputs in a `$_SESSION['attempted_inputs']`

Upon failed server-side validation, user would be redirected back to the original form where an error message will be printed and all fields will be prefilled with attempted inputs, thus eliminating the need for JS validation.

Assuming attempted inputs will be properly sanitized upon saving and server resources are not a concern on my clients small-scaled applications, what could be the downsides of using this method instead of a classic js client-side approach ?

Thanks

Comment: JS is more user friendly. It's immediate and does not require a round-trip to the server. However users can bypass it easily so it must be coupled with server-side validation. If you omit JS then you're just making your page less user friendly (and dare I say modern looking?)

Answer (score 0):

Downsides:

- Unnecessary start/save/delete of the session. The GC process could do a lot of unnecessary work. You could use a POST back style instead of session saving. I know you said you don't care about performance, but this could bite you back someday.
- Slower validation. Going back and forth with the form isn't a nice UX. If you can say what's wrong before posting it, you should do it.

If i can think of more downsides i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

While this is not the right place to ask for concepts, I just wanted to give you a quick heads-up.

You should **always** validate your inputs on the server side. Manually changing requests these days with tools as the developer console, makes your application really vulnerable to many kinds of attacks.

Comment: All my user input **are** server-side validated. It's written in my question